# aws sqs starts up with an NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, spring-4

I am using spring 4.1.x, to create a producer to put messages into AWS SQS. 
I created a configuration class for QueueMessagingTemplate. I get the below error during application start up. There seems to be some dependency conflicts after reading couple of posts, but was not able to figure out the exact issue. Could someone help with the issue:

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

SQS Config File:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SQSConfig {

    @Bean
    public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate() {
        return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync());
    }

    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync() {

        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsStaticCredentialsProvider =
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("AKIASMLCYIZLTWCAQJRG", "JFuBfHgJvSSNGTvWk939Xs8dWAoNAQkVfDVNWAu1"));
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-2")
                .withCredentials(awsStaticCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.EmployeeRESTController.queueMessagingTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessagingTemplate' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 67 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessagingTemplate' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 69 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 81 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.setSerializedPayloadClass(AbstractMessageConverter.java:157)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.support.AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.initMessageConverter(AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate.<init>(QueueMessagingTemplate.java:96)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate.<init>(QueueMessagingTemplate.java:74)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate.<init>(QueueMessagingTemplate.java:54)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig.queueMessagingTemplate(SQSConfig.java:35)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e690f18.CGLIB$queueMessagingTemplate$0(<generated>)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e690f18$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$96660a53.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e690f18.queueMessagingTemplate(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 82 more
22-Feb-2020 02:08:55.128 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRESTController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller.EmployeeRESTController.queueMessagingTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessagingTemplate' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queueMessagingTemplate' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 69 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'queueMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 81 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.setSerializedPayloadClass(AbstractMessageConverter.java:157)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.support.AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.initMessageConverter(AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate.<init>(QueueMessagingTemplate.java:96)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate.<init>(QueueMessagingTemplate.java:74)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate.<init>(QueueMessagingTemplate.java:54)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig.queueMessagingTemplate(SQSConfig.java:35)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e690f18.CGLIB$queueMessagingTemplate$0(<generated>)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e690f18$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$96660a53.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
        at com.howtodoinjava.demo.config.SQSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e690f18.queueMessagingTemplate(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 82 more
```